How can I establish a relationship in laravel based on a group of custom keys?
I have a main model which is named Tour and I have another model OptionPrices. How can I establish a relationship based on this conditions
option_prices table
+-------+---------+----------+
| id    | channel | optionid |
+-------+---------+----------+
| 12531 |    9278 |    10003 |
| 12533 |    5408 |    10003 |
| 12530 |    5501 |    10003 |
| 12529 |    3862 |    10003 |
| 12535 |    9225 |    10003 |
| 12536 |    6640 |    10003 |
| 12534 |    6111 |    10003 |
| 12532 |    5235 |    10003 |
| 12492 |    3862 |    10002 |
| 12491 |    6640 |    10002 |
+-------+---------+----------+

A tour can have many option_prices but its not using the id, it is based on the optionid column BUT it must be grouped by so it will became one optionid
I am planning to use a pivot table but the problem is I think it will attach multiple option_prices and when I am getting the OptionPrices relation, it will result in multi query?

Can you explain what you're trying to solve and provide the schema for the rest of the tables?

basically i just want a relation with hasMany or belongsToMany without using the primary key id and use the other key(optionid) via groupBy @Ken

If you want to use other foreignkey you can do like this in your model
Tour Model:
public function options(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(OptionPrice::class, 'optionid', 'id');
}

OptionPrice Model:
public function tour(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tour::class, 'optionid', 'id');
}

You can specify your relation base on the column name in the database using eloquent pivot

hmm i see. but is it okay to do that one? the optionid must be groupedBy.

You can access the optionId in the child using [with] (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method it is groupedBy automatically by its parent
